# Simple method to display a popup message from within an Apex Class

Tags: apex, popup

We have a ProcessBuilder that is triggered when a certain checkbox is checked on a Contact. The processbuilder calls an @Invokable Apex function that creates an object and performs some other tasks. We want to display a user friendly message (rather than the system generated error message) if the object creation throws an error. I have been searching but can't seem to find a simple approach. We are just using the standard Salesforce page. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you have designed it, this can't be done.

- The Process Builder starts on a DML action which is at the database layer of the application. Thus, PB automation occurs regardless of input stimulus - UX, REST API, scheduled job, scheduled flow, Data Loader, Bulk API, etc.  The PB-caught error offers no opportunity for "friendlificaton" although the invocable Apex's catch block can help somewhat by throwing a new error with a clearer message.

To show a friendly message to the user you have to:

- Use some form of code that wraps the UX initiation such as a VF, Aura, LWC or screen flow driven off a button/quick action
- The controller/client-side logic catches the error and displays the message to the user